# merge two arrays by specific fields

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array that looks like
$firstArray

```
[0] => Array(
   [ID] => 1
   [Fruit] => Apple
   [State] => Ohio
    )
 [1] => Array(
   [ID] => 2
   [Fruit] => Orange
   [State] => Hawaii
    )
 [2] => Array(
   [ID] => 3
   [Fruit] => Orange
   [State] => Vermont
    )
```

And another array which looks like
$secondArray

```
 [0] => Array(
   [ID] => 1
   [description] => This is sample description
   [Price] => 20
    )
 [1] => Array(
   [ID] => 1
   [Fruit] => This is sample description 2
   [Price] => 15
    )
 [2] => Array(
   [ID] => 2
   [Fruit] => This is the second description
   [Price] => 100
    )
 [3] => Array(
   [ID] => 2
   [Fruit] => This is the second description 2
   [Price] => 50
    )
 [4] => Array(
   [ID] => 3
   [Fruit] => This is the third description
   [Price] => 99
    )
```

I have used

```
$newArray = array_merge_recursive($firstArray, $secondArray);
```

This has only appended entries from the second array to the end of the first array ideally i would want the new array to look like this

```
 [0] => Array(
   [ID] => 1
   [Fruit] => Apple
   [State] => Ohio
   [description]
       Array(
         [0] => This is sample description
         [1] => This is sample description 2
    )
   [price]
       Array(
         [0] => 20
         [1] => 15
    )
 [1] => Array(
   [ID] => 1
   [Fruit] => Apple
   [State] => Ohio
   [description]
       Array(
         [0] => This is the second description
         [1] => This is the second description 2
    )
   [price]
       Array(
         [0] => 100
         [1] => 50
    )
```

Essentially the new array should be combined on the ID and create nested arrays from the second array.

Comment: Please use PHP var_export() when you post PHP data constructs here.  This gives us your data in the form of PHP executable code.  We can copy/paste into code examples that demonstrate the principles, without having to do a lengthy process of turning print_r() data into PHP code!  Thanks.

Comment: I don't think you're going to get this from a stock PHP function.  Use a couple of `foreach` loops, it shouldn't be more than a few lines of code.

Comment: Your question is Not clear , what you actuclly want?

Comment: @JagdishChaudhary He wants the array to look like the one he posted ;) I guess the question is clear. But as FKEinternet said, probably not possible with stock functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this makes sense.  https://iconoun.com/demo/temp_jumpman.php

```html
<?php // demo/temp_jumpman.php
/**
 * Dealing with PHP nested arrays
 *
 * https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45145282/merge-two-arrays-by-specific-fields
 */
error_reporting(E_ALL);
echo '<pre>';

// TEST DATA CREATED FROM THE POST AT STACK - ID, Fruit, State
$first = Array(
 '0' => [
   'ID' => '1',
   'Fruit' => 'Apple',
   'State' => 'Ohio',
    ],
 '1' => [
   'ID' => '2',
   'Fruit' => 'Orange',
   'State' => 'Hawaii',
    ],
 '2' => [
   'ID' => '3',
   'Fruit' => 'Orange',
   'State' => 'Vermont',
    ],
);

// TEST DATA CREATED FROM THE POST AT STACK - ID, description, Price
$second = Array(
 '0' => [
   'ID' => '1',
   'description' => 'This is sample description',
   'Price' => '20',
    ],
 '1' => [
   'ID' => '1',
   'description' => 'This is sample description 2',
   'Price' => '15',
    ],
 '2' => [
   'ID' => '2',
   'description' => 'This is the second description',
   'Price' => '100',
    ],
 '3' => [
   'ID' => '2',
   'description' => 'This is the second description 2',
   'Price' => '50',
    ],
 '4' => [
   'ID' => '3',
   'description' => 'This is the third description',
   'Price' => '99',
    ],
);

$out = [];
foreach ($first as $arr)
{
    // PLACEHOLDERS FOR THE FOUND DATA FROM THE SECOND ARRAY
    $arr['description'] = [];
    $arr['Price'] = [];
    $id = $arr['ID']; // THE ID WE WANT IN THE SECOND ARRAY
    foreach ($second as $idp)
    {
        if ($idp['ID'] == $arr['ID'])
        {
            $arr['description'][] = $idp['description'];
            $arr['Price'][] = $idp['Price'];
        }
    }
    $out[] = $arr;
}
print_r($out);
```